# Applying the fundamental theorem of calculus: extremes of integration

Tags: calculus, integration

So I have this exercise in which I need to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to calculate the derivative $G'(x)$ to the following function for $x> 1/2$

$G(x) = \int_{1}^{2x^2} \frac{1}{1+4t^2} dt$

So first i thought that $G$ is a composition of differentiable functions

$G_1(x) = \int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{1+4t^2} dt$

$g(x) = 2x^2$

So I will have to apply the derivation rule

$G'(x) = G_1'(f(x)) \times f'(x)$

Ok...

Now For calculating $G_1'(x)$ I will apply the fundamental theorem of integral calculus which tells us that $G_1'(x) = f(t)$ where $f(t) = \frac{1}{1+4t^2}$.

Now my question is:

They want us to calculate this for $x> 1/2$. I know that if i was calculating an integral i should pay attention to the inversion of extremes (for $1/2 < x < 1/ \sqrt 2$ $2x^2$ is less that 1)... But do i need to pay attention when calculating the derivative? Or do I simply calculate the derivative ignoring my $x$ value.

Thanks!

P.S. - If the answer is "you need to invert the extremes of integration if $1/2 < x < 1/ \sqrt 2$ do I simply put a minus signal inside the integral and switch the extremes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G(x)$ be given by

$$G(x)=\int_1^{2x^2}\frac{1}{1+4t^2}\,dt$$

Now, let $y=2x^2$ and $g(y)=G(\sqrt{y/2})$.  Then, from the chain-rule, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dG(x)}{dx}&=\left.\frac{dg(y)}{dy}\right|_{y=2x^2}\frac{dy}{dx}\\\\
&=\left.\frac{d}{dy}\left(\int_1^y \frac{1}{1+4t^2}\,dt\right)\right|_{y=2x^2}\frac{dy}{dx}\\\\
&=\left.\left(\frac{1}{1+4y^2}\right)\right|_{y=2x^2}\,(4x)\\\\
&=\frac{4x}{1+4(2x^2)^2}\\\\
&=\frac{4x}{1+16x^2}
\end{align}$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Hi! I think you misunderstood my question... I know how to calculate the derivative (I have no problems with that)... My concern is if the specific x value affects it or not. Can you help me?

Comment: @GrangerObliviate There is no restriction on $x$.  The expression for the derivative is as expressed herein.  Note that if $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$, then $F'(x)=f(x)$ regardless of whether $x<a$ or $x>a$.

Comment: Hi Mark ! I'm sorry I didn't say anything anymore. Your answer was pretty useful and clarified me, even if I already knew how to derivate. My main doubt was about the extremes of integration, but as you said the x value doesn't matter. Thank you very much !

Comment: Granger, you're quite welcome! It was a pleasure.  -Mark