# Restrictions applying fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: integration

About my last question : [Applying the fundamental theorem of calculus: extremes of integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1809008/applying-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-extremes-of-integration/1809015?noredirect=1#comment3696849_1809015)

I still have question in other example that appeared to me

$G(x) = \int_{x}^{x^2} \frac{1}{ln (t^2+1)} dt$

In this case does the value of x matters because when x is lesser than 1 we should invert the extremes of integration, right?

What do you think?

Comment: No need to worry about that!

Comment: If the lower limit is greater than the upper limit, the integral is still well-defined. We conventionally define $$\int_a^b f(t) \ dt = -\int_b^a f(t) \ dt$$